# Saving parquet file in Spark giving error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kerberos, cloudera-cdh, parquet

We are using spark 1.6.1 on a CDH 5.5 cluster. The job worked fine with Kerberos but when we implemented Encryption at Rest we ran into the following issue:-

```
Df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("Partition").parquet(path);
```

I have already tried setting these values with no success :-

```
 sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "true"/"false");   
 sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("parquet.metadata.read.parallelism", 1);

 SparkConf.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema","false");
 SparkConf.set("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown","true");
```

Ideally I would like to set summary-metadata to false as it will save sometime during the write.

```
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter: could not write summary file for hdfs://abc
java.io.IOException: Could not read footer: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file FileStatus{path=hdfs://abc/Partition=O/part-r-00003-95adb09f-627f-42fe-9b89-7631226e998f.gz.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=12775; replication=3; blocksize=134217728; modification_time=1485801467817; access_time=1485801467179; owner=bigdata-service; group=bigdata; permission=rw-rw----; isSymlink=false}
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:247)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:262)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.writeMetaDataFile(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:56)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)
at thomsonreuters.northstar.main.ParquetFileWriter.writeDataToParquet(ParquetFileWriter.java:173)
at thomsonreuters.northstar.main.SparkProcessor.process(SparkProcessor.java:128)
at thomsonreuters.northstar.main.NorthStarMain.main(NorthStarMain.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:558)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file FileStatus{path=hdfs://abc/Partition=O/part-r-00003-95adb09f-627f-42fe-9b89-7631226e998f.gz.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=12775; replication=3; blocksize=134217728; modification_time=1485801467817; access_time=1485801467179; owner=bigdata-app-ooxp-service; group=bigdata; permission=rw-rw----; isSymlink=false}
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:239)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: can not read class org.apache.parquet.format.FileMetaData: Required field 'version' was not found in serialized data! Struct: FileMetaData(version:0, schema:null, num_rows:0, row_groups:null)
at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.read(Util.java:216)
at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.readFileMetaData(Util.java:73)
at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter$2.visit(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:515)
at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter$2.visit(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:512)
at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter$NoFilter.accept(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:433)
at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:512)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:430)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
... 5 more
Caused by: parquet.org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'version' was not found in serialized data! Struct: FileMetaData(version:0, schema:null, num_rows:0, row_groups:null)
at org.apache.parquet.format.FileMetaData.read(FileMetaData.java:881)
at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.read(Util.java:213)
... 12 more
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:854)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:649)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:418)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /10.51.29.22:1004 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:854)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:649)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:418)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:854)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:649)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:418)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /10.51.29.217:1004 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:854)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:649)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:418)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:854)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:649)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:418)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/30 18:37:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /10.51.29.218:1004 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:670)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:854)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:649)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:418)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:237)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:233)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please include more information about your architecture (such as, is Microsoft Active Directory Kerberos used here? Are you using a keytab?), relevant code snippets and add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: We are using Cloudera CDH 5.5 stack with its Kerberos. Spark 1.6.3 deployed on YARN through spark-submit in cluster mode. We use spark.yarn.principal and spark.yarn.keytab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a library conflict issue between open source Spark 1.6.1 and Cloudera's Spark. I changed my POM file to use

```
Spark version :- 1.6.0-cdh5.9.1
```

And now it is working fine.

P.S :- If you run into the following error you might have "spark.shuffle.encryption.enabled" set to true.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intel.chimera.stream.CryptoOutputStream.<init>(CryptoOutputStream.java:124)
at com.intel.chimera.stream.CryptoOutputStream.<init>(CryptoOutputStream.java:113)
at com.intel.chimera.stream.CryptoOutputStream.<init>(CryptoOutputStream.java:102)
at com.intel.chimera.stream.CryptoOutputStream.<init>(CryptoOutputStream.java:89)
at org.apache.spark.crypto.CryptoStreamUtils$.createCryptoOutputStream(CryptoStreamUtils.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:229)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```